# Problems accessing fresh deploy of SpringBoot sample app on Weblogic12C

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I'm having problems accessing the sample springBoot application after I deploy it to Weblogic12C. It works fine using the springBoot-embedded Tomcat server.

## Install and test using SpringBoot-embedded Tomcat: all is well

Steps to reproduce: get the springBoot "getting started" application code following the steps: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

- git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git
- cd gs-spring-boot/complete/ (we'll be using the gr-spring-boot/complete dir so that you don't have to go through the "getting started" page above (all changes done for you in "complete").
- open the file gs-spring-boot/complete/build.gradle and add " apply plugin: 'war' " below the other "apply plugin" entries

At this point, you can validate that all is well by running the gradle "bootRun" tasks which starts the app in the embedded Tomcat server. Once tomcat started, browse to localhost:8080/ and see that you get "Greetings from Spring Boot!"

## Now let's install this on Weblogic 12C

- run "gradle war" (again, work from gs-spring-boot/complete/)
  you will now have a war file under gs-spring-boot\complete\build\libs\complete.war

  - go to your weblogic12C console. I didn't make changes to my WL12C so the console is located at localhost:7001/console NOTE: I downloaded the WL12C developer version one week ago from the Oracle site. I didn't make any changes to it, as downloaded. The dev version of WL12C download requires that we point it to our already installed JDK. My WL12C uses java version:

    > > java version "1.7.0_45"
    > >     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
    > >     Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
  - when in the console, deploy the war file:
  - click on "deployments"
  - click on "install"
  - browse to you "gs-spring-boot \ complete \ build \ libs" dir
  - select the radio button next to complete.war and hit next
  - select "install as application" and hit next
  - leave all options as is [DD only, use the defaults, use same accessibility] and hit next
  - click finish

At this point, you will see that the application deployed fine:
- click on "deployments" again and see that your "complete" springBoot app is listed and ACTIVE
- click on "complete" and notice on this page: "Context Root:   /complete". NOTE: weblogic docs say that if there is no context-root defined in weblogic.xml, then it uses the name of the war file (minus the .war)

## Now, the problem: getting a 403:

if you try to access the springBoot app at localhost:7001/complete you get a 403!!!

```
Error 403--Forbidden
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.4 403 Forbidden
The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
```

Ok, so let's make one final change (I'm fishing here, maybe weblogic really wants a weblogic.xml):

- create the dir: gs-spring-boot\complete\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\
- create this file: gs-spring-boot\complete\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\weblogic.xml
- edit weblogic.xml to contain:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
      <wls:context-root>testApp</wls:context-root>
  </wls:weblogic-web-app>
  ```
- now go back to your weblogic console (localhost:7001/console)
- go to "web applications" and select the checkbox next to "complete" then hit "delete"
- restart your weblogic12C server (just to be paranoid)
- run the "gradle clean" then "gradle war" task again to generate a new war file
- open the war file (using winzip or whatever) and confirm that the war file now has WEB-INF/weblogic.xml
- go to the console the deploy the new war file (use same steps as above)
- confirm that the app is now deployed and has a contextRoot of /testApp (as defined in weblogic.xml)
- browse to localhost:7001/testApp/

The 403 is still there. So:

- weblogic DOES know about this application (returns 403). Because if it didn't know about the application, it would return 404 (try it by going to localhost:7001/doesNotExist and you'll get 404)
- but it looks like WL12C doesn't route requests to spring. In the past, we'd define a bunch of things in web.xml but nowadays, with javaConfig and SpringBoot, this should all be done automagically...

  - note: because SpringBoot uses JavaConfig (Servlet3), we can't use anything lower that weblogic12C (which is the latest)

## Another thing I tried: change RequestMapping

In the sample code above, open the file gs-spring-boot\complete\src\main\java\hello\HelloController.java and replace:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

with this:

```
@RequestMapping("pierre.htm")
```

Now, if you browse to (remember weblogic.xml define context-root as /testApp):

- localhost:7001/testApp/pierre.htm you'll get a 404
- localhost:7001/testApp/           you'll get 403

And if you try on tomcat with "gradle bootrun", you can get to it fine: localhost:8080/pierre.htm (you get "greetings from SpringBoot!").

So this yields the following hints:

- Weblogic does know about /testApp
- Weblogic has no idea what /testApp/pierre.htm is. It's like it was never configured as a RequestMapping.
- there is some "Spring wiring" missing for it to work on weblogic....

This is where I'm stuck... Can anyone think what JavaConfig "wiring" I'm missing to make it work on Weblogic? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

## Solution

If anyone comes here, to make it simpler than read all the comments, below, here's how to make it work:

- start with the SpringBoot sample app and git the "complete" solution from here: spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/
- update the class WebInitializer so that it implements WebApplicationInitializer. So change it from this:

  ```
      public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  ```

To this:

```
        public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
```

- create a new file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml and put this contents in it:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
      <wls:context-root>helloApp</wls:context-root>
      <wls:container-descriptor>
          <wls:prefer-application-packages>
              <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
          </wls:prefer-application-packages>
      </wls:container-descriptor>
  </wls:weblogic-web-app>
  ```

  - gradle war
  - deploy to Weblogic12C
  - it should work now :) Thanks so much to both Dave Syer and Evgeni!

## Previous Solution (kept here for posterity)

- start with the SpringBoot sample app and git the "complete" solution from here: spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

  - in the sample app's package "hello", add a new public class HelloWebXml implements WebApplicationInitializer
  - take all the code from org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer and copy it into HelloWebXml but change these lines:

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application;
    }

To this:

```
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
```

- copy the class org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter into package "hello" in the sample app
- create a new file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml and put this contents in it:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
      <wls:context-root>helloApp</wls:context-root>
      <wls:container-descriptor>
          <wls:prefer-application-packages>
              <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
          </wls:prefer-application-packages>
      </wls:container-descriptor>
  </wls:weblogic-web-app>
  ```

  - gradle war
  - deploy to Weblogic12C
  - it should work now :) Thanks so much to both Dave Syer and Evgeni!

NOTE: There is a similar questions here:
[Deploy Spring Boot app in Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835051/deploy-spring-boot-app-in-weblogic)
...but that other question is about the deployment and it's a little vague (deployment itself works fine for me)

Comment: That sample isn't immediately convertible to a war just by changing the packaging. Did you see the "converting" guides, e.g. https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven?

Comment: AH, good point, I didn't see that. That is definitely part of the "Spring wiring" I was missing. So, I just tried it and still not luck. So, instead of using a version of the code that had my dirty hands on it, I used the "gradle version" of the Maven doc you linked: http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ and used the "complete" folder to generate the war file (it has all the changes mentioned on that page). I use "gradle war" to generate the war and deploy that to WL. Unfortunately, I still get a 403 upon hitting my local Weblogic12C at localhost:7001/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Weblogic is that it looks for a class that **directly** implements `WebApplicationInitializer` to load the context. You probably extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Try to
create a class that implemets `WebApplicationInitializer` and copy the content of `SpringBootServletInitializer` in it(you will need to also copy one package level class from the spring source, so your custom class can see it, as far as I remember).

Comment: That seems kind of broken - `WebApplicationInitializer` is a Spring interface, so WL has no business depending on it. It would be good to hear if this is a solution I guess.

Comment: I created a new public class WebInitializerTwo implements WebApplicationInitializer (in package hello of the SpringBoot "hello" app). And I copied the contents of SpringBootServletInitializer into hello.WebInitializerTwo . I had to copy org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter into package hello because SpringBootServletInitializer line 88 needs it [application.sources(ErrorPageFilter.class);] and it's now in a different package. With the above 2 additional changes and creating the war, weblogic12C now complains, upon deploy/activation. See error in next message:

Comment: the error is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory) Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

Comment: @Pierre you're on the right track :) I remember, that my colleagues faced the same issue. Weblogic supplies the logging library, so there is a conflict. You can tell WL to stop provide the library and use the classpath of your project in the weblogic.xml, but I don't remember how to do it. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic

Comment: @DaveSyer Yes, looks like a bug in the Weblogic.

Comment: I added my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml back to the sample hello app. And I've included prefer-application-packages org.slf4j.* in it. I'm going further now: it deploys fine. But when I access the app, I get 500 internal server error. It's a NullPointerException in my copy of ErrorPageFilter.java:114. I'll try a couple more things. For tracking: the weblogic.xml blurb to add is:
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

Comment: IT WORKS!!! I forgot to change the configure method in my new WebInitializerTwo (package hello); the one that was completely copied over from SpringBootServletInitializer. I forgot to change "return application;" to "return application.sources(Application.class);". Thanks so much to both of you (Dave Syer and Evgeni). I'll update the description to include the solution, including steps to get the sample app to work/deploy on weblogic12C [until this gets ironed out one way or another]!

Answer (score 4):

The soluation by Evgeni works thanks.  But i have an improvement.

Rather than take a copy of the SpringBootServletInitializer and ErrorPageFilter, you can continue to extend it, but simply add a redundant "implements WebApplicationInitializer" to your class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("nz.co.myapp")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    /** Used for running in war */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct. I confirm that this improvement works on Weblogic12C and is a great improvement (no need to copy code, a simple implements does the trick). I'll update the solution in the description above. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

Redundant superinterface WebApplicationInitializer for the type Application, already defined by SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: This does not privede an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: it's redundant in theory yes. But without the redundant declaration, it wasn't working on Weblogic 12C. Current answer still stands.